# Why is this simple conditional expression not working?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Very simple line:

```
i = 3
a = 2 if i in [1, 3, 6] else a = 7
```

fails with:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to conditional expression
```

whereas expanded as:

```
if i in [1, 3, 6]:
    a = 2
else:
    a = 7
```

works fine.

Comment: Sorry guys, every now and then I forget about the extra `=` and end up baffled as to why the line is not working.

Comment: Not a duplicate, previous question was out pros and cons, this is a common copy paste error.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You are using it wrong. Use it this way:

```
a = 2 if i in [1, 3, 6] else 7
```

The general form is:

```
var = val1 if cond else val2
```

Answer (score 11):

Should be

```
 a = 2 if i in [1, 3, 6] else 7
```

You can read it as:

```
 a = (((2 if i in [1, 3, 6] else 7)))
```

which is to say that the expression on the right side of the assignment sign is fully evaluated and the result then assigned to the left side.  The expression itself is two values *separated* by the condition.

Comment: What about:
myvar=array["key"] if "key" in mydict else myvar=default
This doesn't work for me

Comment: Same mistake as the original poster.  Should be `else default` at the end.